# Calc between 2 Cols in Same Table with Different Where Criteria?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with these cols:

| T |
| --- |
| id (PK) |
| dt (DateTime - each row is unique and 1min apart) |
| E (Decimal Value) |
| C (Decimal Value) |
| S (Integer Value of either 1 or 3) |

I need this :

**AVG(T1.C - T3.E)
WHERE MIN(T1.id) > T3.id**

^^^ This is just an example of how I think it needs to be done, but am VERY open to a better way!)^^^

So the T1/T3 tables are simply derived from the main table (T) using:

> (SELECT * FROM T WHERE S = 1) AS T1
>
> (SELECT * FROM T WHERE S = 3) AS T3

**DETAILS**

> - S = 1 for the id/row that C is pulled from
> - S = 3 for the id/row that E is pulled from
> - id/row for E Needs to be > the row/id for C YEARWEEK(dt) for the
> - id/row that C is pulled from needs to = the YEARWEEK(dt) of the row    that E is pulled from.

I can't join them on id or dt as each row has a unique value.

The way I've been trying to accomplish this is to split the original table into either Temp Tables or subqueries but nothing will bring it all together.

Comment: Please consider reading [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Read about "self join"

Comment: I do know about self-joins, but how can I join when there's no common numbers to join ON? A row can't have both 1 and 3 values at the same time- so their ID and DT will always be different. How do you join with that?  Thank you!

Comment: Your task makes no sense in current description. For example. **AVG(T1.C - T3.E)** assimes that separate `C` value taken from 1st subqueriy is related to some `E` from 2nd subquery by some expression whereas you tell explicitly that "I can't join them on id or dt" which means that taking some, for example, `T1.C`, you cannot find acording `T3.E`. I recommend you to demonstrate this everything on some example - provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (~10 rows) and show desired output for this data with detailed explanations. Also specify **precise** MySQL version.